# How to iterate over a SOAP response in SoapUI using XQuery?

Tags: testing, soap, xquery

I have a SOAP response similar to this one:

```
<items>
 <item date="2009-10-02"> </item>
 <item date="2010-10-02"></item>
 <item date="2012-10-02"></item>
</items>
```

And I need to check using xQuery and a regular expression I already have if the dates in every item have the right format. I've tried iteration but it keeps warning me: "More than one match in current response".
This is what I've already tried:

```
 let $items:= (//items)
 for $i in $items
    return 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your xml is not well-formed it missed item end tags. Please correct it! It's also makes easier others to give a solution if you provide what you are already using.

Comment: I corrected the XML but that's not the point of the question, obviously that's not my real SOAP response.

Comment: In what format you want to get the dates?

Comment: That's not important, I just want to get the dates values.

Comment: $i/item[@attrib='date']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query processor supports XQuery 3.0 and you're interested one **combined result for all dates**, use the "every-satisfies" syntax.

```
every $date in //item/@date satisfies matches($date, '[-\d]+')
```

If the processor doesn't support that syntax, you can use something like this:

```
not(//item/@date/matches(., '[-\d]+') != true())
```

If it only supports XQuery 1.0, you might need to wrap `matches` around the XPath sequence:

```
not(matches(//item/@date, '[-\d]+') != true())
```

---

If you're interested in **individual values**, use this:

```
//item/@date/matches(., '[-\d]+')
```

Or again for XQuery 1.0:

```
for $date in //item/@date
return matches($date, '[-\d]+')
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found on my own something that worked:

```
for $z in //item[1]
return matches($z/@date, 'regularexp')
```

Comment: You said you need to check if _dates in every item have the right format_, but you're only checking the first date in this query.